# Search column for specific text and delete entire row with that text

Tags: vba, for-loop

I need to search through a group of email addresses in column K and delete any rows with @noemail.com.  Below is my code attempt.  It was previously working but would only delete one row at a time forcing me to run the macro multiple times.

```
`Sub Prospects()
'
' Prospects Macro
'
' Delete rows with @noemail.com
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim row As Range
    Dim ContainWord As String
' Select range in column K
    Range("K2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Set rng = Selection
' Set noemail as word to search for
    ContainWord = "noemail"
' Loop through each cell in range, test cell contents and clear noemail.com rows
    For Each row In rng.Cells
        If Not row.Find(ContainWord) Is Nothing Then rng.EntireRow.Delete
    Next row
    Range("B2").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
If Not row.Find(ContainWord) Is Nothing Then rng.EntireRow.Delete
```

Specifically the last part: `rng.EntireRow.Delete`.  `rng` is the entire selection and not just those that are filtered.  You are going cell by cell then when it finds one that returns True it deletes the top row of the `rng`

By changing `rng` to `row` you should get the desired effect., like this:

```
If Not row.Find(ContainWord) Is Nothing Then row.EntireRow.Delete
```

edit to deal with loop:

The problem is that when it deletes a line it moves to the next cell.  If there is a "noemail" in the line right below the one that is deleted it moves that one into the row you just tested and skips it.

Try this:

```
Sub Prospects()
' Delete rows with @noemail.com
Dim ContainWord As String
Dim i As Integer
i = 2 ' i is a counter

' Set noemail as word to search for
ContainWord = "noemail"
' Loop through each cell in column K, test cell contents and clear noemail.com rows
Do While Range("K" & i) <> ""
    If Not Range("K" & i).Find(ContainWord) Is Nothing Then
        Range("K" & i).EntireRow.Delete
    Else
        i = i + 1
    End If
Loop
Range("B2").Select
End Sub`
```

This will stay on the same row deleting bad addresses till it encounters a good address then move to the next.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this issue!  That worked but I still need to run the macro multiple times to get all of them.  Is there something wrong with the loop still?

Comment: Do you have blanks in column "K"?

Comment: No, there are no blanks until the addresses end

Comment: @Tom The problem is that when the for loop deletes the line it moves the next line up into its place then moves to the next thus skipping that line.  See my edits.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks so much for your help!